# Vanishing Planets?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

If we put a solid sphere in space, it will lose some molecules which will
form a sort of an atmosphere around it so that we have the required vapour
pressure for solid-vapour equilibrium (Temp. of body is the average temp
of space ~ 3K) Now, this gas has some velocity distribution profile. A
fraction of the molecules will have velocity greater than the escape
velocity of the sphere. This fraction will escape, and more vapour will be
formed, and more molecules will escape. Basically the system will never
attain equilibrium and the solid will finally become gas.

Is there a flaw in this analysis? If not, can we predict the time required
for evaporation for our hypothetical planet given its total mass, initial
radius, molecular mass, etc.?

Comment: Should you not factor in the infall from other evaporated planets?

Comment: Conceptually, I'm guessing you're probably right. However, the vapor pressure of most high-molecular weight materials is vanishingly small, so I would guess that this is a very small effect for anything other than very light molecules and atoms.

Comment: some materials have no significant vapour pressure. Iron, for instance, only reaches a vapour pressure of 1Pa at around 1700K. If you had an iron planet sitting at around 3K, it's vapour pressure would be so low that the protons would probably decay before it boiled away

Comment: @Jim: Haha, that's a long time

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a flaw in this analysis?

Yes, it doesn't point out that as the fastest moving molecules escape, the remaining molecules are at a lower temperature.  In other words, the sphere is cooled by the evaporation process.  There would be two types of cooling, one from sublimation of the solid, and the other from the fastest molecules escaping.

If you want to calculate the evaporation time, you would need to consider the rate of heating from the cosmic microwave background radiation versus the cooling from evaporation.